# Adding features to a vectorlayer using PyQGIS in VSCode

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector-layer, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a plugin that generate a vector layer with geometry using 2 other layers, the first one 'layer_segment'contain features with geometries to dissolve based on common field value between them, the second layer 'layer_iti' contain features with field of which makes the link with the first layer here is my code :

```
def itinDissolve(self):
    
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    layer_iti = self.dlg.comboBox.currentLayer()
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
    layer_segment = self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentLayer()

    ## create a new vectorLayer
    itineraire = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLine?crs=epsg:3948&index=yes", "itinéraire", "memory")

    ## those fields that i'm about to create are the same as the layer_iti's fields
    pr = itineraire.dataProvider()
    fields = QgsFields()
    
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("ID_ITI", QVariant.String,'character', 30),
            QgsField("NUMERO",  QVariant.String,'character', 10),
            QgsField("NOM_OFF", QVariant.String,'character', 100),
            QgsField("NOM_USAGE", QVariant.String,'character', 100),
            QgsField("DEPART", QVariant.String,'character', 50),
            QgsField("ARRIVEE", QVariant.String,'character', 50),
            QgsField("EST_INSCRI", QVariant.String,'character', 1),
            QgsField("NIV_INSCRI", QVariant.String,'character', 3),
            QgsField("AN_INSCRI", QVariant.String,'character', 4),
            QgsField("SITE_WEB", QVariant.String,'character', 254),
            QgsField("AN_OUVERT", QVariant.String,'character', 4)])
    itineraire.updateFields() 
    
    path = layer_iti.source()
    pat = 'C:/Users/aa/test.shp'
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(itineraire,pat,'utf-8', driverName='ESRI Shapefile') ##this part 

    ## in this part i'm tring to dissolve features's geometries if the layer_segment "CODE_ITI" is the same as the layer_iti "NUMERO"
    for feat1 in layer_iti.getFeatures() : 
        
        code_list = feat1['NUMERO']
        geom = None
        
        for feat11 in layer_segment.getFeatures():
            b = str(feat11['CODE_ITI']).split(',')
            
            for c in b :
                for d in code_list : 
                    if c == d :
                            if geom == None:
                                geom = feat11.geometry()
                            else:
                                geom = geom.combine(feat11.geometry())
                
        pr = itineraire.dataProvider()
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setFields(fields)
        feat.setAttributes(feat1.attributes())
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(geom))
        
        
        pr.addFeature(feat)
        itineraire.updateExtents()

    #a try to add feature manually but it doesn't work
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry(geom)
    fet.setAttributes(["Johny", '2', '0','.','3','hy','r','rgy','fdt','dfg','th'])
    pr.addFeatures([fet])
    itineraire.updateExtents()
    itineraire.commitChanges
    
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(itineraire, pat , "UTF-8", layer_iti.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Nothing happened, no error appears, and I still don't have the layer in the folder.

Comment: Without knowing how you call this function it might be hard to determine where it goes wrong, however there is already a problem with the fields you insert in your features, in the loop, `fields` is an empty `QgsField` and outside at the end you don't set any. Also, `writeAsVectorFormat` is depreacated try with the more recent version